# Duplicate Entry error when enabling AD account

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am trying to add users to Active Directory programmatically and I keep running into an error - no matter what user I create as soon as I enable the account a "Duplicate Entry " error is thrown. This is the code that I am using:

```
DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add("CN=" + username, "User");
NewUser.CommitChanges();

//Add user information
NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", password);
NewUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = FirstName;
NewUser.Properties["sn"].Value = LastName;
NewUser.Properties["mail"].Value = email;
NewUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = username + @"domainname";
NewUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Add(0x200);//enable account
NewUser.CommitChanges();
```

When I comment out the line that changes the userAccountControl, everything works fine. I even tried to create a new entry and modify it that way using this code:

```
DirectoryEntry editUser = getUserEntry(username);
editUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Add(0x200);//enable account
editUser.CommitChanges();
```

but that still throws the same error. getUserEntry just grabs the directory entry from AD given the username. Can anyone see a reason why a duplicate entry error would occur in this case?

Comment: From where I look, it would seem you're not setting any value for `samAccountName` - that needs to be set, and needs to be unique for each user account

Comment: I thought that if you do not add the sAMaccountName it automatically gets set to a unique ID. If I comment out the enable account line the disabled accounts all have a unique sAMAccount name ( I looked it up in AD directly), such as:
$V31000-64AQ2483EE3G, $341000-ACDLI5Q4HRVB, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to replace by :

```
DirectoryEntry editUser = getUserEntry(username);
editUser.Properties["userAccountControl"][0] = (0x200);//enable account 
editUser.CommitChanges();
```

You probably know that some attributes can be multi-valued, `userAccountControl` **can't**, but in your code that's what you try to do, I mean to multi-value it. In my code I just assign a new value (it's going to play a replace on the pure LDAP point of vue).